# fwrite does not write but deletes file contents only

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, truncate

everyone!
I've checked 10+ similar questions here and they didn't help.
I have a small script which is supposed to write contents of some value from  $_GET[] and write it to file.
The script worked for a month but accidentally stopped.
Now it only truncates file.

file is writable for apache user:
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 apache root   0 Июл  9 07:39 ipnt

```
$newips2=trim($_GET['newips2']);
if ($newips2) {
echo ('debug: #newips2:'.$newips2.'<br>');
if ($handle2=fopen('ipnt','w')) { 
        fwrite($handle2,$newips2);
        fclose($handle2);
        echo ("updated<br>");
} else {
        echo ("file isn't open for writing<br>");
}
}
```

I see that $newips2 is not empty and see "updated" in output, so if  statement resolves to true.
 I've even tried to use

```
fflush($handle2)
```

and

```
ftruncate($handle2,ftell($handle2));
```

and tried to add 'b' to fopen modes.

I've enabled error  reporting in .htaccess:

```
php_value error_reporting E_ALL 
php_value display_errors On
php_value display_startup_errors On
```

But still no errors displayed. No luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you are out of space in that server? try `df -h` to see how much space you have left.

Comment: Thanks Dekel! You were right It was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

After read document http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fopen.php, if you wath add new line end of file you need to fopen with a.

```
$newips2=trim($_GET['newips2']);
if ($newips2) {
    echo ('debug: #newips2:'.$newips2.'<br>');

    if ($handle2=fopen('ipnt','a')) { 
        fwrite($handle2,$newips2 . "\n");
        fclose($handle2);
        echo ("updated<br>");
    } else {
        echo ("file isn't open for writing<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, I don't want to add, i want to erase and write over

Answer (score 0):

It was really stupid reason: no disk space.
Moderators, you just could delete this whole question.